# How can i get balance of bitcoin address not exist in my wallet?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, armory

How can i get balance of bitcoin address not exist in my wallet ?

I try to use bitcoin-Abe but it is complicated and take seral days to full database with blockchain.

Is there exists other tools like bitcoin-Abe but easy and fast to parse blockchain, i want from parse blcokchain to get balance and transactions of bitcoin address ?

Does armory contain any facility to parse blockchain or get balance of any address and it's transactions ?

Comment: how about an online service via web request?

Comment: can you give me example of online service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple online Services which can do this.

For Example [Blochain.info](http://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_api):

http://blockchain.info/address/12sENwECeRSmTeDwyLNqwh47JistZqFmW8?format=json

There you get a field called final_balance and all transactions for this bitcoin address.

If you dont need so many information you can use this [Query API](http://blockchain.info/q):

http://blockchain.info/q/addressbalance/12sENwECeRSmTeDwyLNqwh47JistZqFmW8

Here you will get only a number as return value which represents the amout of bitcoin in satoshi for this address.

Another example is [biteasy.com's REST-API](https://support.biteasy.com/kb/rest-api/getting-started):

https://api.biteasy.com/blockchain/v1/addresses/12sENwECeRSmTeDwyLNqwh47JistZqFmW8

Comment: Mentioning blockexplorer.com is simply a crime. It's old and explodes all the time and there are much better alternatives out there than this.

Comment: good interjection, i guess blockchain.info is the best service for this at the moment, just wanted to show that its not the only one out there, but your right, blockexplorer is probably not the best example

Comment: Well, not everybody agrees that it's the best service but yes, it has been around for some time now.

Comment: Just recognized that Biteasy.com also offers such an API, I added it to my post

Answer (score 1):

If you have bitcoind running, you can get balance without using bitcoin-abe.
Basically you need addrindex enabled in bitcoin. A simple script can get all transactions of a given address and then calculate the balance. You can use https://github.com/cnu1439/blockchain-utils

Answer (score 0):

Your wallet implementation is programmed to compute only the balance of the addresses you own. Remember that the concept of a "balance" is really just the sum of the values of the unspent transaction outputs (UTXOs). The original client however does not have the function to perform this computation on any given address.

This means you're either stuck using 3rd-party services like Blockchain.info, or simply the more cumbersome tools like bitcoin-abe you mentioned.

Comment: you know other tools easy rather than bitcoin-Abe